# How would I return one string at a time from a 2d array and not have any repeating ouputs until i have used the entire list?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods

I am trying to make a thing that selects one of five names from a 2d array of strings and return it. I only want to return one name at a time so I am using methods, but I also want the names to not repeat until all of them have been generated. I found something that was almost what I needed. However the output was still in a list and if I put it in a method it would just repeat.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
  import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  static void runArray() {
        String[] peoples = {"Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4"};
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList(peoples);
    Collections.shuffle(names);
    for (String name : names) {
      System.out.println(name + " ");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    runArray();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some expected input/output or clarify the behaviour you expect? The input in your question is a bit confusing as you talk about a 2d array but are using a 1d array and it's unclear what you are actually attempting to accomplish. Based on what you've described it shouldn't be too hard, just a case of understanding exactly what you need.

Comment: @Barnesly sorry about the confusion. as long as I can get names names out of an array it will be fine I just assumed that doing it with a 2d array would be easier. but basically to state my question again. I need to output 1 random name out of a list of 5 names every time i call a method. when a the method outputs a name from the list i need the name to not be able to be output again until i run the method 4 more times and all the names are used. let me know if that makes any more sense. again sorry if im a little slow im still a begginner at this.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense - I'll post an answer in a bit

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added an answer but think you actually aren't for off doing what you are asking - all I've really done is shuffled things around so you have a method to call which returns a name as and when you need it (whether in a loop or otherwise). Hopefully it helps but if not let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to randomly remove an item from the list each time you want to process a name, and continue to do so while there are more names left in the list.

e.g.

```java
    private static final Random R = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private static String getRandomFromList(List<String> list) {
        final int index = r.nextInt(list.size());
        return list.remove(index);
    }

    private static void processName(String name) {
        // do stuff here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] peoples = {"Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4"};
        final List<String> names = Arrays.stream(peoples).collect(Collectors.toList());


        while (!names.isEmpty()) {
            final String name = getRandomFromList(names);
            // Now do your processing for the name here e.g.
            processName(name);
        }
    }
```

So you can call `getRandomFromList` 4 times (in the above example), getting a random name each time which you can then process. Rather than assuming a specific number of entries I have just put this in a while loop with a check on whether there are any names left.

If you need to call it more sequentially you can do something like below. It's good to make sure there are actually names left in the list and if not you can write out an error and return early, or throw an exception.

```java
if (names.isEmpty()) {
    return; // or log error, or throw exception
}
String name = getRandomFromList(names);

// do stuff with first name

if (names.isEmpty()) {
    return; // or log error, or throw exception
}
name = getRandomFromList(names);

// do stuff with second name

// etc.
```